# Change PDF printing scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

For some reason when I try to print a pdf file from my website it's being cut at the end. I search a little and changing the scale of the page in the printing pluging/menu it prints perfect.

I don't want my clients having the same problem, so there is a way so adjust this manually before opening the printing pluging? I'm opening to sugestions

OK:

[image: This prints OK]

NOT OK:
[image: This is not OK]

Comment: It might be your browser. Have you tried it in a different browser/machine?

Comment: @PrerakSola the problem is that this has to work at least in Chrome and Mozilla, even if the browser is the problem I have to find a fix for it